# Windows Forms C# Buttons in TableLayoutPanel Margins being overwritten

Tags: c#, winforms, button

Buttons very close to each other.

Component Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Drawing;


namespace CustomExplorer.Components
{
    public partial class RunningApps : TableLayoutPanel
    {
        public RunningApps()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public RunningApps(IContainer container)
        {
            container.Add(this);

            InitializeComponent();
            this.ColumnStyles.Clear();
            this.RowStyles.Clear();
            this.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Percent, 100));

            this.HandleCreated += new EventHandler(this.Form_Load);
        }

        private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Process list and spawn buttons
            List<WindowData> ar = WindowsTasks.GetActiveTasks();
            this.ColumnCount = ar.Count;
            this.MinimumSize = new Size(50 * ar.Count, 54);
            this.Size = new Size(50 * ar.Count, 54);
            for (int i = 0; i < ar.Count; i++)
            {
                this.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Percent, 100 / this.ColumnCount));
                Button button = new Button();

                WindowData w = ar[i];

                // Setup Button Style
                button.Name = string.Format("Button_{0:D}", i);
                button.Text = string.Format("Button_{0:D}", i);
                button.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
                button.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
                button.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;

                // Icon
                button.Image = w.icon.ToBitmap();
                button.ImageAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;

                // Sizes
                button.MinimumSize = new Size(50, 54);
                button.Margin = new Padding(5);
                button.Size = new Size(50, 54);

                // Utils
                this.Controls.Add(button, i, 0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The way buttons are exposed:

[image]

The function gives the running process that have "Graphics", add them all to Array ar. Then the for loop adds columns for each of the buttons and them other for loop add the buttons with the image

Tried all that I could found. Margins, Paddings and stuff seems to be only applied at the first Button.

The component is imported to a tablelayout at main Component

Comment: well, I think part of the issue is you aren't accounting for that margin 5 (being 10), which is added to control size (thus 60). as controls get added, you continuously lose 10 px in difference.  The other part of these observations relates to control anchoring and column overflow behavior.

Comment: try setting ` button.MinimumSize` and ` button.Size` to (40, 44), it still may not be desirable, but it should make the display uniform.

Comment: @BrettCaswell thanks, but its still buggy

Comment: Please never ever use `ArrayList` in any .NET program. It was superseded back in C# 2.0. It's now just a great way to introduce bugs into your code.

Comment: @Enigmativity What should i use then? Coded for all this time in python and js. I have almost any knowledge in C#

Comment: @JohnKlabacher - `List<WindowData>`. Then you don't have to do that awkward cast when you retrieve values and you're never able to add the wrong type to the list.

Comment: @JohnKlabacher - Also, I'd suggest you get rid of the static class `Functions`. It's such a bad anti pattern to put a bunch of unrelated code into a `Functions` or `Util` class. Name the class something that matches what it's doing. Like maybe `WindowsTasks.GetActiveTasks()`.

Comment: @JohnKlabacher - One further trap to avoid: your `icon` field/property is a disposable. It's usually best for a `WindowData` like class to hold a `byte[]` and return an `Icon` from a `CreateIcon()` function so that the calling code knows it has to call the `.Dispose()`. If you don't call dispose on these types then you can quickly run out of GDI handles and you get unhelpful "Out of Memory" errors.

Comment: This: `this.MinimumSize = new Size(50 * ar.Count, 54);` and the line that follow compromise the layout. You can of course set a MinimumSize, but do that after the TLP's layout has completed. Set it to AutoSize instead, add your Button in a `SuspendLayout()` / `PerformLayout()` section. After that, set the minimum size, which will consider the internal padding, the Buttons' margin and the separators (visible or not) -- Don't subscribe to event in a Custom Control, override the method i.e., override `OnHandleCreated()` instead of subscribing to the `HandleCreated` event

Comment: Not clear why you named the event handler `Form_Load`, which can be quite *confusing* -- Also not clear what `InitializeComponent()` is doing or why you're trying to use this Custom Control as a Component